# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Application only works with HTTP or HTTPS, not both

Tags: facebook, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm creating an application (with the Desktop Browser web page environment) using Worklight 6.0. My problem is this: my application only works in either HTTP or HTTPS but not in both.

When I tried to run my app, it returns:

```
The application failed connecting to the service
```

How can i build my app for both, and deploy it? because I want to put this app on the Facebook canvas, but it only works on HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Aren't Facebook apps HTTPS-only? The Canvas URL should be in HTTPS as welll.

Comment: you can put your http url on the facebook canvas, the problem is that i cant call the:
https://  domain /project name/apps/services/www/ app name/desktopbrowser/default/app name.html

and:

http://  domain /project name/apps/services/www/ app name/desktopbrowser/default/app name.html

as well, one doesnt work

Comment: AFAIK all URLs should be the same one and not both. In any case, it should be transparent. Facebook should not be talking directly with Worklight; rather there should Apache or alike in front of Worklight, which will handle the requests to Worklight, be them HTTPS or HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the application or the environment you've added to your application, but the server. Requests from the Worklight Server are either HTTP or HTTPS, they cannot be both.

But IMO this is irrelevant. I think the correct approach is to put Apache or alike in-front of Worklight (or WebSphere, in your case, which hosts Worklight Server since you've deployed it there), and its job is to handle incoming and outgoing connections - be it HTTPS or HTTP.

That said, AFAIK in Facebook only HTTPS should be used.